# What is the precision of long double in C++?

Tags: c++, precision, long-double

Does anyone know  how to find out the precision of `long double` on a specific platform?  I appear to be losing precision after 17 decimal digits, which is the same as when I just use `double`.  I would expect to get more, since `double` is represented with 8 bytes on my platform, while `long double` is 12 bytes.

Before you ask, this is for Project Euler, so yes I *do* need more than 17 digits.  :)

**EDIT:** Thanks for the quick replies.  I just confirmed that I can only get 18 decimal digits by using `long double` on my system.

Comment: Is it possible that it's converting things to regular double at some point?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible.  I was up until 2AM checking my code for that last night, and I'm pretty sure it's long double all the way through, though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can find out with `std::numeric_limits`:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <limits>       // std::numeric_limits
int main(){
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: will that tell you the precision, or just the limits?

Comment: it tell you the precision. i.e how many digits you can have in the double. min() and max() tell you the limit

Comment: More specifically it'll tell you how many you can round into a long double and not lose the digit.

Comment: yeah, while min() and max() will tell you the limit you can have even if you loose precision. max is 1.18973e+4932 here, while digits10 is 18.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm getting the same results, 18 decimal digits.  Now I'm wondering why 4 extra bytes of storage are needed to get one more decimal digit?

Comment: On x86 it tends to be the 80-bit extended format: 64bits of mantissa, 15bits of exponent, probably going to be around 18 round safe digits. Double is 53bit mantissa or 16 round safe digits.

Comment: What about `max_digits10` vs `digits10`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [<cfloat>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/). Specifically:

```
LDBL_DIG
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It's LDBL_DIG that gives the decimal digits.  LDBL_MANT_DIG gave me the binary digits.