# very long double

Tags: c++, precision, long-integer

I know that for very long ints there is int64.
Is there something similar for very long doubles?
I want to save a number with a very big precision.

Comment: There is a _float128 type in newer gcc which is software floating point with <= 128 bit precision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long double` is the largest standard type. If this isn't enough, you'll need a bignum library (e.g. [GMP](http://gmplib.org/))

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at:

[What is the precision of long double in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476212/what-is-the-precision-of-long-double-in-c)

It depends upon the implementation.

I got a feeling there might be something in the new standard c++0x about long double, but I forget, will check shortly.

Edit: checked it, my bad, there is no change: long double is at least as good as double.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out http://gmplib.org/

> GMP is a free library for arbitrary
>   precision arithmetic, operating on
>   signed integers, rational numbers, and
>   floating point numbers. There is no
>   practical limit to the precision
>   except the ones implied by the
>   available memory in the machine GMP
>   runs on. GMP has a rich set of
>   functions, and the functions have a
>   regular interface.