# Decimal Precision Lost after 15th Digit - Bad PI

Tags: c, math, double-precision

Attempting to print more than 15 decimal digits of `PI` result in incorrect decimals printing after the 15th decimal. This despite the 30 correct decimal values being assigned and despite using `long double` to hold the value. The following test case clearly shows the error.

This was unexpected. If there would be any error in the digits, I would not expect to see any error until the 25th digit after exhausting the IEEE-754 significand. What rule is in play here that might explain by I can't print back the same 30 digits I just assigned to sPI below. This also affects the ability to print the representations of `M_PI` contained in `math.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void) {

    // static PI approximation (glibc man 1.17)
    long double sPI = 3.14159265358979323846264338327;
    char strPI[]   = "3.14159265358979323846264338327";

    printf ("\n %s (strPI - string - correct)\n", strPI);
    printf (" %.29Lf (sPI - long double - INCORRECT)\n\n", sPI);

    return (0);
}
```

output:

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327 (strPI - string - correct)
3.14159265358979311599796346854 (sPI - long double - INCORRECT)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Presumably, this decimal error would apply to any decimal number with greater than 16 decimal precision. When printed as a string, PI prints fine (obviously), but when printed as a double  -- the decimal precision breaks down after the 15th decimal. What is causing that?

Very interesting, as suggested adding an `L` at the end of the floating point literal did help:

```
 3.14159265358979323846264338327 (strPI - string - correct)
 3.14159265358979323851280895941 (sPI - long double - INCORRECT)
```

That provided 3 additional decimals of precision.  For clarity, this was run on Linux 3.14.1 kernel, gcc 4.8.2 on an old AMD Phenom X4 9850. (AMD Turion Based Laptop & Intel P4 gives same result)

Attempting with `quadmath.h` and `__float128` type assigned to `sPI`, the results were the same as for the long double. A few more digits were available, but precision still broke down on the 19th digit:

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327 (strPI - string - correct)
3.1415926535897932385128089594061862 (sPI - long double - INCORRECT)
```

Comment: Looks like `long double` is still 64-bit double precision. Not all compilers support the 80-bit extended precision and the ones that do may require a compiler switch.

Comment: You haven't said what compiler you are using. Many compilation platforms offer 80-bit `long double` (GCC on Linux/x86, Clang on Linux/x86, …) but even more define `long double` as the same type as `double` (Visual Studio). Note: even if `long double` was the 80-bit extended precision floating-point format, you wouldn't get 30 π decimals digits out of it, more like 19-21.

Comment: You realise that assigning a `double` or `long double` constant to anything with more precision will not make you happy, right?  Use the `l` suffic for `long double` and parse the constant from a string if you're going past `long double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double precision floating point values are represented as a 64 bit value, with finite precision of 15-16 decimal digits. It would therefore appear that `long double` is implemented as 64 bit double precision on your system.

In case you are not familiar with these issues, I highly recommend David Goldberg's timeless article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Thank you David. That was the document I could not get to come back in my search. I was stranded reading addendums to FXT, MPFR, GnuMP, and trying to find the page that explained it, but alas. So we get 15 digits in the real world unless using a multi-precision lib.

Comment: Some systems have a `long double` that could be 80 bits, and others 128 bits. And others, like yours it would seem, have 64 bit `long double`. But types like `long double` will always have finite precision. For more precision you need specialised libraries.

Comment: That also explains why the only way to output the digits of `PI` in the algorithms that compute it to millions of places is one digit at a time. That also was confusing at first. I had a little snippet of code that could correctly print `PI` to any decimal number desired -- but it did it one at a time.

Answer (score 5):

You are not storing the 'long double' value into the variable, but the default `double` instead. The compiler reads the floating point value, stores it as a default type, and only casts it to *long* double "afterwards". You can see this when you compare its value to a "normally" assigned `double`.

To hint the compiler to store the constant as a `long double`, add the modifier suffix `L` or `l` at the end of the floating point constant.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    // static PI approximation (glibc man 1.17)
    double sPI_d     = 3.14159265358979323846264338327;
    long double sPI  = 3.14159265358979323846264338327;
    long double sPI_L= 3.14159265358979323846264338327L;
    char strPI[]     ="3.14159265358979323846264338327";

    printf ("\n %s (strPI - string - correct)\n", strPI);
    printf (" %.29f (sPI - double)\n", sPI_d);
    printf (" %.29Lf (sPI - long double - INCORRECT)\n", sPI);
    printf (" %.29Lf (sPI - long double - BETTER)\n", sPI_L);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 3.14159265358979323846264338327 (strPI - string - correct)
 3.14159265358979311599796346854 (sPI - double)
 3.14159265358979311599796346854 (sPI - long double - INCORRECT)
 3.14159265358979323851280895941 (sPI - long double - BETTER)
```

See also [What is the precision of long double in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476212/what-is-the-precision-of-long-double-in-c) -- you cannot expect more than around 18 significant digits for a `long double`.

Comment: Thanks Johnware - I will also investigate `quadmath.h` and `__float128` to see if I can get another place or two with 80 bit floating point.

Comment: `quadmath.h` seems interesting! Bog standard `math.h` defines lots of digits, but it seems casting `(long double)M_PI` comes "too late", as I still got its double value.