# String of numbers to double in c

Tags: c, string, char, double

I'm trying to convert a simple string in c to a double with:

```
 double n;
 sscanf_s(str, "%lf", &n);
 printf("%lf", n);
```

taking into account that:

```
const char *str[] = {"37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"};
```

When I try to print n , the numbers is good until the 16th digit. The out is something like:

```
371072875339021043110257403....
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: because floating-point types in C have limited precision (~15-17 digits for [double-precision IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). [Double precision - decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9999221/995714). On some platforms you can use `long double` to get a few more digits though [Decimal Precision Lost after 15th Digit - Bad PI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24485846/995714)

Comment: Because floating point is kind of like scientific notation.  Your number is represented internally as the binary equivalent of 3.710728753390210 x 10^49, and you only get about 15 digits past the decimal in the mantissa.

Comment: There is no type under an ordinary compiler on an ordinary machine that will let you represent a number like 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250 with full precision. (That number needs at least 165 bits.)  You would have to use a separate arbitrary-precision library.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

`sscanf_s(str, "%lf", &n);` expects a `char *`, not a `char **`.  Enable all compiler warnings to see such problems and be sure to cut/paste problems correctly.

```
const char *str[] = {"37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"};
```

Did you mean the following?

```
const char *str = {"37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"};
```

---

A `double` usually can *exactly* encode about 2<sup>64</sup> different values as a `double` is often a 64-bit piece of data.
*37107287533902 102798797998220837590246510135740250* is not one of them.

Output like the following is reasonable:
*37107287533902 1043110257403....*

*37107287533902 104311025740304689820495323650000000.0* is the closest representable `double`.

*37107287533902 099118728881769862191964827320000000.0* would have been the next best choice.

Notice in this range, *exact* `double` are 2<sup>112</sup> apart (about 5.2*10<sup>33</sup>). Such is the binary nature of most `double` encodings.